# HTACCESS : How to FILTER A STRING anywhere in the full URL string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say there are a few URL schemes, like:

- http://www.example.com/foo/bar/bas
- http://www.example.com/foo/fooo/bas/bar/bas
- http://www.example.com/foobarbas
- http://www.example.com/?foobar=bas
- http://www.example.com/?barfoo=bas
- http://www.example.com/?bas=foo&bar=bas

I want to DROP (e.g. returns `404`) all the URLs whenever it contains a string: `bar` inside.

Please kindly help. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents complete http request (including REQUEST_URI and QUERY_STRING) as received by Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} bar [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` is nice, hadn't noticed that one before. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} bar [OR]
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} bar
RewriteRule .* /404 [L]
```